# Files required for dbexpress application to access mysql databases

Tags: mysql, delphi, deployment, dbexpress

Which additional files are needed to deploy a delphi dbexpress based application to get access to mysql databases.

I can't find any information about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need deploy these files

- libmysql.dll (mysql client library)
- midas.dll (if you use midas)
- dbxmys.dll or dbexpmysql.dll (dbexpress driver,the name changes depending on the version of delphi you use)
- dbxconnections.ini
- dbxdrivers.ini

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can download and install the [MySQL Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/). You probably will want the ODBC drivers.